# ViewWillAppear getting called when the view actually does disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, viewwillappear

I have a custom UITableViewController subclass and the viewWillAppear of this does get called in a weird order when a full screen transitions (away from the view that has the TableView as a subview) happens.

So if I do a full screen transition whereas both screens have the custom UITableViewController, this happens:

```
1 -viewWillDisappear (oldTableViewController)

2 -viewWillAppear (oldTableViewController)

3 -viewWillAppear (newTableViewController)

4 -viewWillDisappear (oldTableViewController)
```

so basically, when viewWillDisappear should only get called once, it calls disappear, appear, disappear on the viewController that just disappears from the screen. This caused the problems and I still have no idea how and why this can happen. I checked for all kinds of addSubview calls etc, but nothing like this is happening here.

Here's the stacktrace of the mysterious and wrong viewWillAppear call, does anyone know where it comes from and how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using iOS 8?